# Printing text to row and column coordinates in Python?

Tags: python, string, printing, coordinates

I haven't found anything about this, but maybe that's because it isn't possible. But is there a way to print text to coordinates in Python? For example, if I wanted to print the string 'A' at the 3rd row and 5th column of the command window, how could I do that? I found ways to get around it and print two different strings at different coordinates using \n for rows and repeating spaces for columns, but it's just too tedious to write the code.

Comment: I think you can create a function, and then print it with that number of spaces in front, between, and after? I am not sure if that's what you asking for. `def printCorrdinate(myString, x, y):`

Comment: @George I'm asking if there is a function that has as arguments the x and y coordinates that you wish to print the text to. See Output() in TI-BASIC: http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/output

Comment: Maybe check out this http://docs.python.org/howto/curses.html#windows-and-pads

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. The curses library comes standard and is documented [here](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html). There are probably others but that will do what you're looking for. In particular, `curses.getsyx()` might be what you need.

Comment: I have Windows 7... Not Unix. Curses doesn't seem to be installed with my build (Python 2.7.2), or at least not working properly.

Comment: Hi. I see. Try Console found at http://effbot.org/downloads . I haven't used it much, but it could help. The documentation at http://www.effbot.org/zone/console-handbook.htm seems to indicate it can do what you're looking for.

Comment: There is no Console for 2.7... Most up-to-date version is 2.6

Comment: PyGame MIGHT do what I want it to. I've had that installed since Monday but haven't done anything with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid the curses module, you can get right down to the basics by using ANSI escape sequences. A quick explanation of the relevant cursor-moving codes can be found [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html). These work right out of the box on Linux/Unix, for Windows you'll need the [coloroma](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) package.

For a cute, cross-platform example using this technique for animation, see [here](https://gist.github.com/sontek/1508912).